# Producer consumer using only 1 additional semaphore

Tags: multithreading, operating-system, mutex, semaphore

[Solution traditional to producer-consumer](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/producer-consumer-problem-using-semaphores-set-1/)

In Operating-Systems, as you see in the link above for producer consumer, two semaphores `full` and `empty` are used, why is it *not possible* to do this using only one quantity semaphore `fullEmpty`.

What I mean is, we have a binary semaphore `mutex` and another semaphore `fullEmpty`, which is initially `0` because there are no items in the buffer, so why do we **need** 2 semaphores (`full`, `empty`)?

The only thing is the order of `wait` and `signal` need to be changed so that the updating of `fullEmpty` is within the critical section.

Any thoughts or reasons?

Comment: Please provide pseudocode so we can tell you why it won't work.  An unbounded P-C queue is fine with only one semaphore and a mutex, but a bounded queue tht works correctly with multiple producers/consumers requires two semaphores and the mutex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key statement in the description that relates to your answer is **"We have a buffer of fixed size."**

For the sake of answering your question, let's first assume that the buffer can expand to fit as many items as needed, or in other words the buffer can grow to an unlimited size. In this case, the only synchronization that would need to occur between producers and consumers (apart from locking the mutex to ensure that you don't corrupt items in the critical section) would be ensuring that consumers only consume items *after* they have been produced by a producer. You could solve this problem with just a mutex and one semaphore. Here is some code, which I borrowed and changed from the link you shared:

**Producer**

```
do {
    //produce an item

    wait(mutex);

    //place in buffer

    signal(mutex);
    signal(full);

} while (true);
```

**Consumer**

```
do {
    wait(full);
    wait(mutex);

    //remove item from buffer

    signal(mutex);

    //consume item

} while (true);
```

As you can see above, the producer is always able to add things to the queue (apart from when the mutex is being held) and doesn't need to wait for consumers to consume anything because the buffer will never fill, even if the consumers don't consume items. On the other hand, consumers can't consume anything until producers have produced items.

---

To answer your question, you need to focus on the statement, "We have a buffer of fixed size." This changes the problem. Since the buffer is no longer able to grow to an unlimited size, **you need to get producers to wait when the buffer is full before they can add more things to the buffer**. This is why you need a second semaphore. Not only do consumers need to wait for producers, but now producers need to wait for consumers. You get producers to wait for consumers by getting them to call `wait` on a semaphore that only consumers call `signal` on.

You can't do this with only one semaphore because the conditions when a producer has to wait are different from the conditions when a consumer has to wait. Since producers and consumers should each be able to decrement and advance past the semaphore under different conditions, you can't use the same semaphore for both.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. My logic was that if we have a *counting semaphore* which is already given a fixed `n` as a parameter, even for the version that has "buffer with bounded size," why can't we use just one semaphore `full` as you used in the first example? 


I mean to say with this counting semaphore, we are guaranteed that we cannot `signal(full)` if `full` is max capacity as defined. I thought we can do in this Java like `Semaphore full = new Semaphore(n, true)`?

Comment: @BrijendarBakchodia Thanks for clarifying. One of your assumptions is invalid. Semaphores have no maximum count: you can call `signal()` on a semaphore as many times as you want: the call will always succeed without blocking (of course, I'm ignoring integer overflow here, but that's not something to worry about for your question). `n` is simply the initial count that you assign to a semaphore - not the maximum count.

Comment: @BrijendarBakchodia Thus, since you cannot block on `signal()`, you must use two different semaphores. If you could set a maximum count for a semaphore and then block on `signal()` once this count is reached, then you could just use a single semaphore.

Comment: @BrijendarBakchodia Of course, it is possible to implement a semaphore that does have a maximum count. That decision is up to the designer. The traditional semaphores that I use and learned about in class do not have a maximum value.

Comment: Hi Jack. That makes a lot more sense... I was thinking `new Semaphore(n, true)` bounds the semaphore's value to a maximum of `n` and minimum of `0`. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is because there 2 conditions you have to wait for: the queue is empty and the queue is full. But classic semaphore allows you to wait only for one condition - wait until semaphore is not 0.

You *can* solve this problem using a single synchronization object, but such object needs to be more feature-full than a semaphore. "Bounded semaphore" - semaphore that has a maximum value should be enough as it allows you to block waiting for both conditions.

How to get one is another question:

- You can build one using mutex and condition variable.
- [Window's semaphore](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/WinBase/nf-winbase-createsemaphoreexa) already has this functionality.
- You can use [`futex`](https://linux.die.net/man/2/futex) on Linux (see `FUTEX_WAIT`, `FUTEX_WAKE`) or equivalents on other OSes: on FreeBSD use [`_umtx_op`](https://nxmnpg.lemoda.net/2/_umtx_op) (see `UMTX_OP_WAIT`, `UMTX_OP_WAKE`), on Windows 8 and newer use [`WaitOnAddress`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/synchapi/nf-synchapi-waitonaddress), [`WakeByAddressSingle`](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/windows/desktop/api/synchapi/nf-synchapi-wakebyaddresssingle)/[`WakeByAddressAll`](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/windows/desktop/api/synchapi/nf-synchapi-wakebyaddressall).

I suggest you to get familiar with `futex` interface - with it you can build more powerful and more efficient synchronization objects than regulars ones. Today most OSes provide an equivalent interface and even C++ might introduce something similar in the future (see [`std::synchronic<T>`](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2015/p0126r0.pdf)).

---

Few notes:

Linux has [`eventfd`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/eventfd.2.html) which can act as a semaphore when created with `EFD_SEMAPHORE` flag, but it has maximum value of `0xfffffffffffffffe` and it cannot be changed. Maybe some day this syscall will be extended to support maximum value too.